# Change the value of a public variable javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the value of a public variables with a function and use this new values from an other function.

My use case: I want to set a default public variable for a countdown timer, and if the user wants to change the target date he could put a new date. To do so, I've created another function to change the public variables, but it doesn't seem to work perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
<table id="global" border="3">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <form name="formInput" action="#">
                <label>Choose new Date: </label>
                <input type="date" name="field1" Id="txtvarInput" />
                <br />
                <br />
                </label>
                <div class="form-actions" "span3">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Select" onclick="alertVal()" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="countdownTimer">
        <td>
            <script type="application/javascript">
                var current = "Has been launched!"; //-->enter what you want the script to display when the target date and time are reached, limit to 20 characters
                var year;
                var month;
                var day;
                var hour = 0;
                var minute = 0;
                var second = 0;
                var ampm = "pm";
                var timezone = -5;

                function alertVal() {
                    var theInput = document.getElementById('txtvarInput').value;
                    var date_array = new Array();
                    date_array = theInput.split("-");
                    month = date_array[1];
                    year = date_array[0];
                    day = date_array[2];
                }


                var Countdown_Ignition = new Countdown({
                    width: 300,
                    height: 60,
                    year,
                    month,
                    day,
                    hour,
                    ampm,
                    minute,
                    second,
                    timezone,
                    rangeHi: "day",
                    style: "flip" // <- no comma on last item!!
                });
            </script>
        </td>
```

The issue is that when I change the date, my second function doesn't take the new values.

Comment: Note, the argument to `new Countdown()` is not valid.

Comment: @Arvind It's valid in ES6, using object literal shorthand notation.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have public variables, do you mean global variables? Which variables aren't being changed?

Comment: The `Countdown` object doesn't use the global variables, it uses whatever options you provide when you initialize it. Initializing them from global variables doesn't mean it will keep using those variables, it just gets the values of them.

Comment: How about moving the code var Countdown_Ignition = new Countdown({}) into your alertVal() function? As Barmar mentions you are initializing a new intance with the new Countdown code and not declaring a function.

Comment: I tried to move Countdown_Ignition = new Countdown({}) and sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't work, I know it's a bit weird, but I believe the reason behind is sometimes when I hit the select button who calls function alertVal() the page reload, and all the variables get initialized, I'm wondering  why the page reloads when i submit an input data !

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't work because you're passing a **value** on the object literal (pointing to `undefined` at first), so when your `alertVal` function "updates" the value, it's making an assignment pointing to the new value (i.e. `22`).

If you want to keep track of the change *inside* the `Countdown` object, you have to pass a variable which points to an actual object (a reference, not a value). So, your global function updates a property of the very same object and you win!

```
var publicObject = {
    year: null,
    day: null,
    etc: null
};

function setData(){
   publicObject.day = 'new value';
   publicObject.year = 'new value';
   publicObject.etc = 'and so on';
};

var  Countdown_Ignition = new Countdown({
                                            width:300, 
                                            height:60,
                                            publicObject,
                                            rangeHi:"day",
                                            style:"flip"       // <- no comma on last item!!
                                        });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, however, I think the reason behind is when i hit the select button after choosing the date the page reloads and all the variables get initialized! any idea why the page reloads, and how can prevent that. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you're using a `submit` button, so the form is submited after click... using the onclick="" method you have to `return false` in your `alertVal()` function in order to cancel the default click on button, avoiding the submit.